# Qt check for valid URL

Tags: c++, qt, url

I am trying to create a Qt application which checks if a URL entered by the user into a text edit is valid.

This is what I have so far but it only ever says the URL entered is valid, even when I enter one which is not.

```
bool checkUrl(const QUrl &url) {
    if (!url.isValid()) {
        //qDebug(QString("Invalid URL: %1").arg(url.toString()));
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString usertext = ui->plainTextEdit->toPlainText();
    QUrl url = QUrl::fromUserInput(usertext);
    if (checkUrl(url))
        ui->textEdit->setPlainText("Valid URL.");
    else
        ui->textEdit->setPlainText("Invalid URL.");
}
```

Also on the qDebug line there is an error:

```
/home/user/HTML/mainwindow.cpp:32: error: no matching function for call to ‘qDebug(QString)’
```

Does anyone know what the problem is as it keeps returning true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `qDebug` like this:

```
qDebug() << QString("Invalid URL: %1").arg(url.toString());
```

also note that `QUrl::isValid()` does not check syntax of url. You may want to use regular expressions to validate urls.

Answer (score 1):

`QUrl::isValid()` only basically checks if the character encoding is right. What are you considering a wrong url?

Re `qDebug`, the form you use basically encapsulates `printf`, so it doesn't work with `QString`. You want to do:

```
qDebug() << QString("Invalid URL: %1").arg(url.toString());
```